# Trait method that can be implemented to either return a reference or an owned value

Tags: reference, rust, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to define a trait with a method that can be implemented to either return a reference or an owned value.

Something like:

```
struct Type;
trait Trait {
    type Value;
    fn f(&self) -> Self::Value;
}
impl Trait for () {
    type Value = Type;
    fn f(&self) -> Self::Value {
        Type
    }
}
impl Trait for (Type,) {
    type Value = &Type; // error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
    fn f(&self) -> Self::Value {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

This piece of code doesn't work though, since `&Type` is missing a lifetime specifier. I'd want `&Type` to have the same lifetime as `&self` (i.e. `fn f<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Type`), but I don't know how to express this in Rust.

I managed to find a couple of ways to make this code work, but I don't love either of them:

1. Adding an explicit lifetime to the trait itself:

   ```
   trait Trait<'a> {
       type Value;
       fn f<'b>(&'b self) -> Self::Value where 'b: 'a;
   }
   impl<'a> Trait<'a> for () {
       type Value = Type;
       fn f<'b>(&'b self) -> Self::Value
           where 'b: 'a
       {
           Type
       }
   }
   impl<'a> Trait<'a> for (Type,) {
       type Value = &'a Type;
       fn f<'b>(&'b self) -> Self::Value
           where 'b: 'a
       {
           &self.0
       }
   }
   ```

   What I don't like of this solution is that anything using `Trait` needs an explicit lifetime (which I believe is not intrinsically necessary), plus the trait seems unnecessarily complicated to implement.
2. Returning something that might or might not be a reference - like [`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

   ```
   trait Trait {
       type Value;
       fn f<'a>(&'a self) -> Cow<'a, Self::Value>;
   }
   impl Trait for () {
       type Value = Type;
       fn f<'a>(&'a self) -> Cow<'a, Self::Value> {
           Cow::Owned(Type)
       }
   }
   impl Trait for (Type,) {
       type Value = Type;
       fn f<'a>(&'a self) -> Cow<'a, Self::Value> {
           Cow::Borrowed(&self.0)
       }
   }
   ```

   What I don't like of this solution is that `().f()` is a `Cow<_>`: I'd need to call `().f().into_owned()` to obtain my `Type`. That seems unnecessary (and might result in some negligible run-time overhead when using `Trait` as a trait object).

   <sub>Also note that `Cow` is not good since it requires that `Self::Value` implements [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) (thus, practically, [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html)), which is too strong of a requirement. It's anyways easy to implement an alternative to `Cow` without such constraints.</sub>

Are there any other solutions to this problem? What's the standard/most common/preferred one?

Comment: "Adding an explicit lifetime to the trait itself" is exactly how I'd do it (although probably with just one lifetime). Perhaps you could further explain why you "believe is not intrinsically necessary", because to me it does seem extremely necessary — you *need* to tie a lifetime to the `Self` type in order to prevent using the reference after the value goes out of scope.

Comment: @Shepmaster: oh, you mean `trait Trait<'a> { type Value; fn f( &'a self ) -> Self::Value; }` ? I was sure that I tried it and it didn't work, but apparently I'm very wrong.  You're right anyways, reading your comment and defining the trait without `'b` made me realize that `'a` needs to be intrinsic of the trait...

Comment: Yep, and I'd use `impl Trait<'static> for () { ... }`, but other than that...

Comment: @Shepmaster Why?  Is there any difference in function, or is it a matter of showing intent?  Thanks man, you're really helpful around here.

Comment: Mmm, thinking a bit more, `'static` might not work; it might make *calling* the method actually impossible. Would have to play with it to figure out.

Comment: I think you're right -- https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=09557b8092604be9d9919f2d4b64a53b&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @peoro: *I'm trying to define a trait with a method that can be implemented to either return a reference or an owned value.* => Iterators do this, the key question however is **a reference to what**? Is it a reference pointing inside `Self`, or is it pointing to an unrelated object which `Self` has a reference to?

Comment: @user1935361: If you don't need to bind to `Self`, it [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=09557b8092604be9d9919f2d4b64a53b&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Well, either? In the provided example it's a reference to an object within `self` (i.e. `&self.0`), but I believe that if I wanted to `impl<'a> Trait for (&'a Type, )` the reference would possibly be `self.0`.

Comment: @peoro: I've presented my arguments as a solution; it seems easier to make myself understood with code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be solved using an additional associated object to choose between whether to return a type or a reference, plus some meta-programming magic.

First, some helper types:

```
struct Value;
struct Reference;

trait ReturnKind<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> {
    type Type: ?Sized;
}
impl<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> ReturnKind<'a, T> for Value {
    type Type = T;
}
impl<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> ReturnKind<'a, T> for Reference {
    type Type = &'a T;
}
```

`ReturnKind` is a "type-level function" which returns `T` when the "input" is `Value`, and `&T` for `Reference`.

And then the trait:

```
trait Trait {
    type Value;
    type Return: for<'a> ReturnKind<'a, Self::Value>;

    fn f<'a>(&'a self) -> <Self::Return as ReturnKind<'a, Self::Value>>::Type;
}
```

We produce the return type by "calling" the type-level function `ReturnKind`.

The "input argument" `Return` needs to implement the trait to allow us to write `<Return as ReturnKind<'a, Value>>`. Although we don't know what exactly the lifetime Self will be, we could make `Return` bound by *all* possible lifetime using [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) `Return: for<'a> ReturnKind<'a, Value>`.

Usage:

```
impl Trait for () {
    type Value = f64;
    type Return = Value;

    fn f(&self) -> f64 {
        42.0
    }
}

impl Trait for (f64,) {
    type Value = f64;
    type Return = Reference;

    fn f(&self) -> &f64 {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: (f64,) = ( ().f(), );
    let b: &f64 = a.f();
    println!("{:?} {:?}", a, b);
    // (42,) 42
}
```

---

Note that the above only works when the `Value` type has `'static` lifetime. If the `Value` itself has a limited lifetime, this lifetime has to be known by the `Trait`. Since Rust [doesn't support associated lifetimes yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md#staging), it has to be used like `Trait<'foo>`, unfortunately:

```
struct Value;
struct Reference;
struct ExternalReference;

trait ReturnKind<'a, 's, T: ?Sized + 'a + 's> {
    type Type: ?Sized;
}
impl<'a, 's, T: ?Sized + 'a + 's> ReturnKind<'a, 's, T> for Value {
    type Type = T;
}
impl<'a, 's, T: ?Sized + 'a + 's> ReturnKind<'a, 's, T> for Reference {
    type Type = &'a T;
}
impl<'a, 's, T: ?Sized + 'a + 's> ReturnKind<'a, 's, T> for ExternalReference {
    type Type = &'s T;
}

trait Trait<'s> {
    type Value: 's;
    type Return: for<'a> ReturnKind<'a, 's, Self::Value>;

    fn f<'a>(&'a self) -> <Self::Return as ReturnKind<'a, 's, Self::Value>>::Type;
}

impl Trait<'static> for () {
    type Value = f64;
    type Return = Value;

    fn f(&self) -> f64 {
        42.0
    }
}

impl Trait<'static> for (f64,) {
    type Value = f64;
    type Return = Reference;

    fn f(&self) -> &f64 {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<'a> Trait<'a> for (&'a f64,) {
    type Value = f64;
    type Return = ExternalReference;

    fn f(&self) -> &'a f64 {
        self.0
    }

}

fn main() {
    let a: (f64,) = ( ().f(), );
    let b: &f64 = a.f();
    let c: &f64 = (b,).f();
    println!("{:?} {:?} {:?}", a, b, c);
    // (42,) 42 42
}
```

But if having the lifetime parameter on the trait is fine, then OP already provided an easier solution:

```
trait Trait<'a> {
    type Value;
    fn f<'b>(&'b self) -> Self::Value where 'b: 'a;
}

impl<'a> Trait<'a> for () {
    type Value = f64;
    fn f<'b: 'a>(&'b self) -> Self::Value {
        42.0
    }
}

impl<'a> Trait<'a> for (f64,) {
    type Value = &'a f64;
    fn f<'b: 'a>(&'b self) -> Self::Value {
        &self.0
    }
}
impl<'a, 's> Trait<'s> for (&'a f64,) {
    type Value = &'a f64;
    fn f<'b: 's>(&'b self) -> Self::Value {
        self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: (f64,) = ( ().f(), );
    let b: &f64 = a.f();
    let c: &f64 = (b,).f();
    println!("{:?} {:?} {:?}", a, b, c);
    // (42,) 42 42
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*[@kennytm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm) presented an excellent (if complex) solution; I wish to propose a much simpler alternative.*

There are two possibilities to provide the lifetime name for the value:

- at the trait level: `trait Trait<'a> { ... }`
- at the method level: `trait Trait { fn f<'a>(&'a self) -> ... }`

The latter is not well supported by the language, and while more flexible is also quite more complicated. However, it also happens that the former is often enough; and thus without ado I present you:

```
trait Trait<'a> {
    type Value;
    fn f(self) -> Self::Value;
}
```

`f` consumes its output, this is fine if `Self` is an immutable reference as those are `Copy`.

The proof is in the pudding:

```
struct Type;

impl Trait<'static> for () {
    type Value = Type;
    fn f(self) -> Self::Value {
        Type
    }
}

impl<'a> Trait<'a> for &'a (Type,) {
    type Value = &'a Type;
    fn f(self) -> Self::Value {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

And it can be invoked without issue:

```
fn main(){
   ().f();
   (Type,).f();
}
```

This solution is certainly not as flexible; but it's also significantly simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! To be honest I believe I prefer the solution of using `trait Trait<'a> { type Value; fn f( &'a self ) -> Self::Value; }`: it's about as *complex* to use as what you're suggesting (anything that uses the trait needs an explicit lifetime in both cases) and doesn't consume `Self`, which I prefer. Anyways it's nice to see alternatives like this one which might be better for other use cases.

Comment: @peoro: Note that in the case of implementing `Trait` for `&'a T`, consuming self doesn't matter: `&'a T` is `Copy`. I would be wary of `Trait<'a> { fn f(&'a self) }`, you may accidentally "pin" your objects with this. Use kennytm's solution of introducing a fresh lifetime for `self` instead.