# Traits, returning a reference to an owned field via a trait method that returns `Self::Item`

Tags: rust

Returning a reference to an owned field is allowed in other scenarios. For instance, the code below compiles fine.

```
struct Charlie<T> {
    delta: T,
}

impl<T> Charlie<T> {
    fn delta(&self) -> &T
    {
        &self.delta
    }
}
```

I'd like to return a reference to an owned field from a trait method in similar fashion. Assume that `Alpha` is a trait in the standard library, so I can't modify it.

Is there a way to implement this?

```
trait Alpha {
    type Item;
    fn bravo(&mut self) -> Self::Item;
}

impl<T> Alpha for Charlie<T> {
    type Item = &T;
    
    fn bravo(&mut self) -> Self::Item
    {
        &self.delta
    }
}
```

The above doesn't compile and the error messages don't seem to apply. If I try following the error message suggestions, things just get complicated and I run into a series of errors with suggestions that also don't pan out.

```sh
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:22:17
   |
22 |     type Item = &T;
   |                 ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
22 |     type Item<'a> = &'a T;
   |              ^^^^   ^^^
```

I've tried the above suggestion and went so far as to declare `'a` on `Charlie`'s struct and add a `PhantomData` field, and thoroughly peppered the rest of my sources with `'a`s. And the compiler continues whining and complaining and nagging throughout the whole process.

I managed to find [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43323250/7915759), but the solutions there seem to all require modifying the trait.

I'm thinking what I'm trying to do may not be possible. But I don't really understand why not.

The `Alpha` trait method that I was struggling with is actually

```
    type Item = Take<&I>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> { ... }
```

I was trying to return another wrapped iterator type, where `I` is the wrapped iterator. The `Iterator` trait itself doesn't define any lifetimes I can leverage.

I do know a way to implement around this limitation using the smart pointer classes to encapsulate the field I want to share in `Charlie`. Then make that my `Item` type. I was just hoping for something with less overhead.

Comment: This use-case is a motivation for [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) which would use the `type Item<'a>` syntax to introduce a generic lifetime. Unfortunately, this feature is not yet stabilized.

Comment: I figured I might be running up against something that others had found a need for but wasn't in the distros yet. Thanks for the reference @kmdreko.

Answer (score 1):

The contract for that trait unfortunately doesn't allow it.

```
trait Alpha {
  type Item;
  fn bravo(&mut self) -> Self::Item;
}
```

This says that, if `Self` is an `Alpha`, then "there exists some single `Self::Item` which I can get from *any* `&mut self` with *any* lifetime". You want "there exists a class of `Self::Item` whose lifetimes relate to `&mut self` in a nontrivial way".

The easiest way to get around this is to make `bravo` take `self` by value.

```
trait Alpha {
  type Item;
  fn bravo(self) -> Self::Item;
}
```

Now, the contract says "there's some way to get a `Self::Item` from a `self`", which is much simpler. We can implement it as

```
impl<'a, T> Alpha for Charlie<&'a mut T> {
  type Item = &'a T;
    
  fn bravo(self) -> Self::Item {
    &self.delta
  }
}
```

Comment: The actual trait I was struggling with on this problem was [Iterator::next(&mut self) -> Self::Item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html). So I can't really modify that. I was trying to return another wrapped iterator type as a reference.