# Trait function returning reference to owned value

Tags: rust

I want to define a trait where a function returns a reference to a value owned by the structure implementing the trait. I currently have:

```rs
trait Foo<'a> {
    type Id;
    fn id(&'a self) -> &'a Id;
}
```

I would like to understand if there's a way to remove the lifetime parameter from the trait. I was looking into lifetime GATs, but couldn't figure it out. I found these two StackOverflow questions:

- [Traits, returning a reference to an owned field via a trait method that returns `Self::Item`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67955249/traits-returning-a-reference-to-an-owned-field-via-a-trait-method-that-returns)
- [Trait method that can be implemented to either return a reference or an owned value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323250/trait-method-that-can-be-implemented-to-either-return-a-reference-or-an-owned-va)

They seem related, but not quite sure how to relate them to my use case.

So, my questions:

1. Is there any way to avoid adding a named lifetime parameter to the trait?
2. If (1) is "no", what would be the Rustacean way to have traits for abstracting away members of structs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to (1) is in most cases "yes", but before going into the details, let me start off with a silly question: have you tried omitting the lifetime parameter in the simplest possible way, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b778659d656ecf3d9f348e672239a8e)? That way a lifetime is still assumed, but it's just the lifetime of `&self`. That will neatly cover the needs of types that return a reference to some data they own or can reach.

Comment: Oh... I feel very dumb now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to remove the lifetime parameter from the trait is to do just that:

```
trait Foo {
    type Id;
    fn id(&self) -> &Self::Id;
}
```

A lifetime is still assumed, but thanks to lifetime ellision, it's simply the lifetime of `&self`. That will allow implementers of the trait to return references to the data they own (or any lifetime longer than that), which is what you wanted.